# How to convert one element lists to float

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract pressure values from openFoam output log.

I read the lines of file as strings and extract floats using:

```
pressure = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+', line)
```

Then, I'm trying to convert string values to float values with:

```
press[dummy1] = [float(p1) for p1 in pressure]
```

I expect this would simply give me an array of floats, however I get something like:

> [[], [1502.79], [1016.86], [752.515], [776.874], [877.85], [989.854],
>   [1139.05], [1402.28], [1305.71], [1547.23], [1389.58], [998.685],
>   [799.895], [711.647], [1507.87], [1753.06], [1438.93], [1119.76],
>   [1001.05], [941.412], [676.467], [772.924], [1063.77], [1537.84],
>   [1732.5], [1342.52], [1053.91], [966.436], [1017.93], [1260.55],
>   [1226.71], [1031.25], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I can't do any mathematical operations with its elements and when I try to convert single element of array with:

```
something = int(press[3])
```

I get following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

What does numbers in [] represent? Is it one element list or something else? And what to do with it?

Comment: If it's one-element list, just do `[0]` to get that one element.

Comment: _I'm trying to extract pressure values from openFoam output log._ Please share at least part of that data, and a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
[press.append(float(p1)) for p1 in pressure]
```

Comment: What's the point of doing this in a list comprehension? Won't it result in a list full of `None`?

Answer (score 6):

Because using the `.findall()` function of `re` returns a list with the matches. When **none** is found, then the return is an empty list, when there's something, it returns a list with all the results, if you are iterating over values in a list then you will get one of two:

1. Empty lists when the regex is not present.
2. 1-value list when the regex is present.

The simplest way to deal with is to add `[0]` to the result of the `.findall()` function.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of string.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it doesn't do what I need. If I write it as you showed I get results as: [[], [1.0], [1.0], [7.0], [7.0], [8.0], [9.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [9.0], [7.0], [7.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [9.0], [6.0], [7.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [9.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ...

Comment: True, you need to use the [0] in the findall, before actually doing the list comprehension as it will also provide an error for empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

Variations on a theme: if you have a "mixed" list of integers, lists, and empty lists, you could process it like:

```
mixed_list = [[], [1502.79], [1016.86], [752.515], 0 , 0]

result = [item[0] if isinstance(item, list) and len(item) > 0 else item for item in mixed_list]

print(result)
```

and it would print:

```
[[], 1502.79, 1016.86, 752.515, 0, 0]
```

And if you also wanted to get rid of empty lists, you could continue processing:

```
result_without_empyt_lists = [item for item in result if item]

print(result_without_empyt_lists)
```

to have:

```
[1502.79, 1016.86, 752.515]
```

of course, it's better to construct the list the way you want it, as exemplified in previous answers, but if you don't have control over how the initial list is constructed, the methods above could work, too.